# Connect two sockets together without writing byte-manipulating plumbing code?

Tags: python, sockets

In Python, is it possible to connect two sockets together without writing byte-manipulating plumbing code?

For example, I would like to write a program that interacts with the user (request/response format) and then after that, performs a TCP connection to another host and then just hands it over to the STDIN/STDOUT sockets.

So then any data received on STDIN would get sent over the TCP socket, and any data received from the TCP socket would get sent to STDOUT - simultaneously, instantly, without either of them blocking.

What is the recommended way of doing this? I'd like to avoid writing a load of socket code if possible and have it 'just work'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because I would like my own software to 'just work' too, but it never happens.

Comment: It's not off-topic. I'd like to know the minimum set of code to write that will perform that function without problems, that's what I mean by 'just work'.

Comment: @MartinJames: The question is of a common form, "does X provide a means to do Y short of the "obvious" but tedious and difficult approach I've already thought of?". Please don't go closing all of these on grounds that it's off-topic to hope that what you want to do can be done easily ;-) It's plausible that some async framework might tie two pairs of file-like objects together for you (and at least should make the plumbing simpler), but if not then a definitive answer that none (currently) does would be something that's not trivial to establish.

Comment: OK, if it's not off-topic, then the answer is 'no', because TCP is a byte/octet streaming service and cannot transfer any messages larger than one byte.  So, if not closed as 'off-topic', I would close it as a dup of the thousands of questions/answers that result from misunderstanding TCP.

Comment: I thought data from TCP arrived in packets, so it's a stream of chunks?

Comment: @Ajjajj - no, it's a stream of octets/bytes.  Anything more complex than that requires a protocol on top of TCP.

Comment: I mean if a packet arrives on a TCP socket, and that triggers your code to the new data into a buffer of a large enough size to accept whatever is in that packet (e.g. 64k buffer), then you will be reading the content of that packet?

Comment: @Ajjajj - in general, nope.

Comment: I think you need to read some basic (I mean, core level, not "simple") networking text to understand what exactly is TCP.

Comment: @MartinJames: standard in and standard out are *also* just streams of bytes/octets, albeit when connected to a tty they are typically both line-buffered and that would have to be disabled to get what the questioner wants. There's nothing in the question about "messages" over the wire or any need to implement any protocol above TCP. Presumably the server will handle whatever the user types, since the client is so dumb.

Comment: @Ajjajj: it's true that TCP splits your stream of data into packets in order to send it over IP (or another Internet layer). By design that is hidden by default from the user of TCP, although of course there can be configuration options. TCP_NODELAY will be important in this case to prevent buffering on send. So abstractly, TCP presents a stream. There's no need at all for the reader to size their buffers to match the size of the IP packets, you needn't read exactly one packet at a time into a buffer, and indeed it would be difficult/impossible to ensure that you did with a typical socket API.

Comment: ... that said, UDP does send and receive a message at a time as opposed to a stream. Basically the whole point of TCP is to break your stream into packets for you and reassemble them in order at the other end, so that you don't have to think about packets. At least, not until you start considering performance.

Comment: @Ajjajj Well, *someone* has to write the plumbing code, since the BSD sockets interfaces doesn't do it by default -- but it doesn't necessarily have to be you.  You might find a library out there that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I was more wondering what the behaviour is when a there is an unlimited size buffer being instantly read (where unlimited >= largest amount of TCP data that can arrive at once, and instantly <= time between two consecutive packets). As I understand it, Internet routing is specified by an IP packet, which encapsulates a TCP packet, which will itself describe an arbitrarily-sized packet of data if the PUSH flag is set, that gets appended to the TCP stream. Can one assume that this packet of data is unsplitable as it passes through the network stack to an application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: my first post didn't answer to what the op wanted. Revised significantly.

```
"""
open another terminal and run
nc -l 8080
type something in the both terminals>
"""
import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from select import select

host = 'localhost'
port = 8080

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host, port))
reader = sock.makefile('r', 0)
writer = sock.makefile('w', 0)
while True:
    ins, _, _ = select([reader, sys.stdin],[],[])
    for i in ins:
        if i == reader:
            sys.stdout.write(i.read(1))
        if i == sys.stdin:
            writer.write(sys.stdin.read(1))
```

Comment: Thank you! With a little bit of tweaking I incorporated it into my code just fine: http://pastebin.com/WpszSEE1 - very much appreciate the help

Comment: oh yeah...reader/writer are not even necessary. It was a leftover from the post before editing.  I'm glad you got it working.  Perhaps the modern approach is to use threads, gevent, or eventlet with blocking calls instead of using select()

Comment: The purpose is to show select() call.  The makefile(_, 0) and read(1) are intentional to avoid buffering for the demo purpose so that the response would appear in the terminal as soon as a line is entered.